# Inserting a value into a URL in android studio?

Tags: java, android, json, url

I sent data from Activity A to Activity B through means of an intent. 
I then extracted the results of the intent via the following.

```
String IdString = questionData.getString("id");
TextView mstudentId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ID);
mstudentId.setText(IdString);
```

I would now like to take the value of IdString which is equal to the value of the string "id" and place it inside a Url. For example,

```
final static String URL_ANSWER = "http//:myFake/(IdString)/Url"
```

How do I go about doing this in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this,

```
final static String URL_ANSWER = "http//:myFake/" + IdString + "/Url";
```

OR 
**UPDATE**

```
String IdString = questionData.getString("id");
TextView mstudentId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ID);
mstudentId.setText(IdString);

final static String URL_ANSWER = "http//:myFake/" + mstudentId.getText() + "/Url";
```

Comment: I cant do that,  as String IdString is located in my oncreate which is a void return type, so I was wondering if there was a new method i needed to create to extract this and if so what is it?

Comment: so where you are setting IdString = questiondata.getString("id"); this??